# EigenVectors of an unitary matrix

Tags: matrices

A matrix $A$ is unitary if $AA^* = A^*A=I$ where $A^*=(\bar A)^T$. I would like to know, Is it true that the eigenvectors of an unitary matrix are its columns? and are these columns orthonormal?

Thanks.

Comment: Please do basic searching before posting questions. See [here](http://sites.millersville.edu/bikenaga/linear-algebra/unitary-and-hermitian-matrices/unitary-and-hermitian-matrices.html)

Comment: @Shailesh it says: *The columns of a unitary matrix form an orthonormal set. *, ok, what about the first question? it doesn't answer that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The columns of an unitary matrix $A$ are othogonal, by definition. But they are not the eigenvectors of $A$, as a simple example shows:
An eigenvector $\vec v$ of $A=\pmatrix{0&1\\1&0}$ is $\vec v=\pmatrix{1\\1}$.